# How to Prove Android ViewModel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I want to ask something that i thought maybe a little bit fundamental. How can i prove that a ViewModel class not get destroyed when there's some configuration changes in Android? In short, how to prove statement below, for example in a logcat on Android Studio?

> The ViewModel class is designed to store and manage UI-related data so that the data survives configuration changes such as screen rotations.

Comment: Why do *you* need to prove it? There are certainly tests at the [activity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/activity/activity/src/androidTest/java/androidx/activity/ComponentActivityViewModelTest.kt) and [fragment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/fragment/fragment/src/androidTest/java/androidx/fragment/app/ViewModelTest.kt) level as part of the libraries themselves.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Validate my code works as it should be, with Android ViewModel of course. Do you have other idea for me to validate my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the `onCleared` method from the `ViewModel`. You can override it.

When the `ViewModel` gets destroyed, `onCleared` will be called.

You'll notice that rotating the screen while in the `MainActivity` or `Fragment` that uses the `ViewModel`, the `onCleared` method will not be called even though `Activity.onDestroyed` does. That is a trait of the `ViewModel`

`onCleared` only gets called when the `Activity` **shuts down**. With something like `Activity.finish` or backpress

Comment: Should I care about disposing or clearing a viewmodel in a `Fragment` or an `Activity` callbacks or `disposables.clear()` in `onCleared()` of the `ViewModel` callback is enough?

Comment: `disposables.clear()` in `onCleared()` is enough, because `ViewModel` is tied to the Activity/Fragment when you created it.

Answer (score 1):

create a `viewmodel` class and declare a variable of it put some data in it and log it or toast the data of `viewmodel` when orientation changed of `activity` :

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

also you need config some element in manifest :

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

the data will stay in view model . if not there would be `nullpointexception` when logging or toasting.

Answer (score -1):

We have many ways to work on your requirement.

- You can use RxJava 2 also for saving your configuration changes.
- You can add config changes in menifest.
- You can use onConfigurationChanged overrided method.